# Regex: Extract a URL surrounded with text

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract URL's from a source code. The source code is similar to the following

```
text text text<h4 class="a"><a href="http://site1.com/url/" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','15',111','','0333','','',home)">...</a></h4>
```

what i reached so far is `(?<=<h4\ class="a"><a\ href=")http://.*` but this still is not extracting only the URL. I need the output to be only `http://site1.com/url/`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use a dom or xml parser instead of regex for parsing html

Answer (score 1):

Like commented, use a dom or xml/html parser instead of regex for that. In a browser, you could do that using javascript:

```js
var s = `text text text<h4 class="a"><a href="http://site1.com/url/" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','15',111','','0333','','',home)">...</a></h4>
`;

var e = document.createElement('div');
e.innerHTML = s;
Array.from(e.getElementsByTagName("a")).forEach(link => {
  console.log(link.href);
})
```

If you don't want to do this in a browser, there are also html and xml parser available for other environments

Answer (score 0):

Capturing groups were designed for tasks like this, although I concur that using a regex for parsing HTML is poor form. If all you need to match is the prefix you've given here and the URL (and you're guaranteed to have well-formed HTML (and properly escaped HTML in any displayed text)) then a regex you can use is:

```
/<h4 class="a"><a href="([^"]+)"/
```

https://regex101.com/r/skfhTm/1

The first capturing group will contain the URL.